# Categorizing Posts in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am having a problem in categorize Posts. I have categories in Post Model, Please help me solve this issue!

**MODELS.PY**

```
html= "html"
css= "css"
python= "python"
javascript = "javascript"
Lang=(
    (html,"HTML"),
    (css,"CSS"),
    (python,"PYTHON"),
    (javascript,"JAVASCRIPT")
)

Broilerplate = "Broilerplate"
Simple_Tags = "Simple Tags"
Elements = "Elements"
Webpages = "Webpages"

Category = (
    (Broilerplate,"BROILERPLATE"),
    (Simple_Tags,"Simple tags"),
    (Elements,"Elements"),
    (Webpages,"Webpages")
)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    language_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Lang, default=html)
    content_1= models.TextField(blank=True)
    language_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Lang,blank=True)
    content_2= models.TextField(blank=True)
    language_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Lang,blank=True)
    content_3= models.TextField(blank=True)
    language_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Lang,blank=True)
    content_4= models.TextField(blank=True)
    language_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Lang,blank=True)
    content_5= models.TextField(blank=True)
    category= models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Category, default=Broilerplate)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    # def update(self):
    #     updated_at = timezone.now()
    #     self.save(updated_at)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def search_by_category(request, category):

    if request.post.objects.filter(pk=request.post.id).first().category == 'Broilerplate':
        nor = request.post.objects.filter(pk=request.post.id).first().category
        print(nor)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(category='Broilerplate')
        category = posts.first().category
        print(category)
        context = {'posts': posts, 'title': category , 'category': category}
        return render(request, 'category.html', context)
    else:  
        context = {'title': category , 'category': category}
        return render(request, 'category.html', context)
```

**URLS.PY**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('html/',PostListView.as_view(), name='CodeWriter_Homepage'),
    path('python/',views.CodeWriter_homepage_python, name='CodeWriter_Homepage_python'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('categroize-by/<str:category>/', views.search_by_category, name='search_by_category'),
    path('post-details/<int:pk>/',PostDetailView.as_view(), name='Post_details_page'),
    path('post-update/<int:pk>/',PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='Post_update_page'),
    path('post-delete/<int:pk>/',PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='Post_delete_page'),
    path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-post'),
    path('new-post/',PostCreateView.as_view(), name='New-post_page')
]
```

**CATEGORY.html**
How can I get the data of the post category in views.py?That will help me very much!

```
  {% block main_post_body %}
    <main class="post-body normal" >
    <p class="post-heading"> Post for <b>{{ category }}</b> :</p>
    {% comment %} <h1 class="mb-3">Search results for <b>{{category}}</b>: </h1> {% endcomment %}
        {% comment %} {% if posts|length < 1 %}
            <h3>No search results found</h3>
            <p>Your search results for <b>{{ query }}</b> is not found.</p>
        {% endif %} {% endcomment %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col span-8-of-12 card">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- <div class="triangle"></div>
          <div class="person-info-card">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col"><img src="{% static 'resoures/css/img/Me.jpg' %}" alt=""></div>
              <div class="col">
                <p>Ketan Vishwakarma</p>
                <p class="post-no">126 Posts | 1k Followers</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> -->
          <div class="col span-1-of-12">
            <div class="person-img" id="person-info-card-toggle">
              <a href="{% url 'User_homepage' post.author.username %}"><img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col span-7-of-12">
            <h3><a href="{% url 'Post_details_page' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> </h3>
            <h4>{{ post.subtitle }}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="col span-1-of-12">
            <a href="#" class="hint--top" aria-label="Like"><span class="ion-md-heart-empty"></span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col span-1-of-12">
            <a href="#" class="hint--top" aria-label="Save Post"><span class="ion-md-add-circle-outline"></span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col span-1-of-12 share">
            <a href="#"><span class="ion-md-share"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-list-share">
              <li><a href="#"><span class="ion-md-copy"> Copy</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="ion-logo-whatsapp"> Share on Whatsapp</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="ion-logo-facebook"> Share on facebook</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="ion-md-more"> More</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col span-1-of-12">
            <a href="#"><span class="ion-md-menu"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-list">
              <li><a href="#">Doesn't work</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="tabs">
          <ul class="tabs-list">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">{{ post.language_1 }}</a></li>
            {% if post.content_2 == "" %}
            {% else %}
            <li class="not-clickable hint--info" aria-label="To view this click Read more">{{ post.language_2 }}</li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if post.content_3 == "" %}
            {% else %}
            <li class="not-clickable hint--info" aria-label="To view this click Read more">{{ post.language_3 }}</li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if post.content_4 == "" %}
            {% else %}
            <li class="not-clickable hint--info" aria-label="To view this click Read more">{{ post.language_4 }}</li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if post.content_5 == "" %}
            {% else %}
            <li class="not-clickable hint--info" aria-label="To view this click Read more">{{ post.language_5 }}</li>
            {% endif %}
            <ul class="categories">
              <abbr title="Categiores">
                <a href="">
                  <span class="ion-md-code-working"></span>
                  {{ post.category }}
                </a>
              </abbr>
              <!-- <li><a href="#">Broilerplate</a></li> -->
            </ul>
          </ul>

          <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <p>
            <pre><code class="language-{{ post.language_1 }}">
                        {{ post.content_1 }}
                                  </code></pre>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>
            <pre><code class="language-{{ post.language_2 }}">
   {{ post.content_2 }}
                                  </code></pre>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p>
            <pre><code class="language-{{ post.language_3 }}">
                       {{ post.content_3 }}
                                  </code></pre>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <p>
            <pre><code class="language-{{ post.language_4 }}">
                       {{ post.content_4 }}
                                  </code></pre>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="tab5" class="tab">
            <p>
            <pre><code class="language-{{ post.language_5 }}">
                       {{ post.content_5 }}
                                  </code></pre>
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'Post_details_page' post.pk %}" class="readmore"><span class="ion-md-arrow-round-down"> Read More</span></a>
        <h6>{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-4-of-12 main-card ">
        <div class="card-small">
          <h1>Result: </h1>
          <div class="result-box">
            <iframe src="" frameborder="0">just for fun</iframe>
          </div>
          <h6>{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y"  }}</</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </main>
  
  {% if is_paginated %}
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                    <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
             {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
  {% endblock main_post_body %}
```

**Note***I have registered the Post model in admin.py*
Tell me the solution to this problem I cannot get the solution I have been trying it for so long and am stuck on this.

Comment: You mean you want to show the data related to a particular ```category```  that is passed as a URL parameter ?

Comment: Yes, I want to show a particular page for a particular category.